# How to maintain normalization when converting normalized WAV files to mp3?

Tags: audio, mp3, wav, sox

I have a script that uses sox to first normalize a bunch of wav files. It then takes the normalized wav files and converts them to mp3. I use the max amplitude stat to check how 'normalized' the files are. The max amp stats of the normalized files are within the same range.  When I look at the max amplitude stats of the mp3 files, they are not maintaining the same close range. How can I maintain normalization when converting from wav to mp3?

The command I use to normalize the files:

```
sox file.wav --norm=-1 norm.wav
```

The command I use to convert the files to mp3:

```
sox norm.wav -c 1 newFile.mp3
```

Comment: It's not going to be exact... remember, MP3 is lossy... but it's going to be very close.  If you disagree, show us how you're calculating your max amplitude.

Comment: I'm just using the sox command to get info about the audio file. It shows the max amplitude as a stat. Like `sox file.wav -n stat`

Comment: just using max amplitude is fragile and any spike will skew results ... instead use a RMS calculation ...  feed it multiple seconds of audio to generate a good power measure ... slide this windows of samples across time to repeat across length of each audio file to give that file one number to represent its ~~volume~~   see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square#Relationship_to_the_arithmetic_mean_and_the_standard_deviation